# how to Add Header and Footer in word Document through XML and XSL in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I want to create a word  document (.doc). I have a xml file and a xslt file. The first one has the data the second has the style. Then I combine these two through my c# code and create the doc file.  Can you please help me into solving the below issues concerning the xslt?    how can I define in each page’s header and footer for word document.It should display in each page.

Answer (score -1):

Reverse engineer it.... Make a document with both of your desired headers/footers and then see how the document generates the two items. I'll be glad to help if a can. This answer is just a quick recommendation.